# Dúvida na comparação de string e listar valor para todas as linhas

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, xls

eu tenho uma tabela de 5 linhas e 5 colunas.
Para cada coluna tenho um nome, por exemplo: Nome, Idade, Sexo, Peso, Altura. E todas as células 5*5 estão preenchidas.

Eu preciso da seguinte formatação:

```
Idade
João - 15
José - 16
Maria - 21

Sexo
João - M
José - M
Maria - F
```

Ou seja, para cada informação da célula eu preciso que me mostre a qual pessoa é relacionada este resultado.

Eu já listo o título (Idade) e o valor (16), porém não consigo vincular o nome a cada informação, ficando:

```
Nome
JOão
JOsé
MAria

Idade
16
15
21

Sexo
M
M
F
```

Eu criei uma varíavel recebendo o valor da célula(x,y), mas imprime vazio.
Segue meu código:

```
   for crange in sheet.merged_cells:                
      rlo, rhi, clo, chi = crange                    
      rranges[(clo,rlo)] = rhi - rlo;
    for col_index in range(sheet.ncols):
      linhas = iter(range(sheet.nrows));             
      nome_mol = ""                                   

      for row_index in linhas:
        if (sheet.cell_value(row_index,col_index) != ''): 
          valor = sheet.cell_value(row_index,col_index);
          if (sheet.cell_value(row_index,col_index) == "NOME"): 
            nome_mol = sheet.cell_value(row_index,col_index)   

            print "{} -- {} |{} |".format(nome_mol, valor)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Estou assumindo que a primeira linha contém os rótulos ("Nome", "Idade", ...) e as demais contém dados. Se isso estiver incorreto, favor editar a pergunta esclarecendo o fato.

Pelo que eu entendi, a coluna com os nomes [das pessoas] é a primeira coluna (índice `0`), certo? De modo que você precisa iterar sobre as demais (`1` a `ncols`):

```
for col_index in range(1, sheet.ncols):
    print sheet.cell_value(0, col_index) # Imprime o nome da coluna
```

Da mesma forma, a primeira linha contém os nomes das colunas, de modo que você precisa iterar sobre as demais:

```
    for row_index in range(1, sheet.nrows):
```

O nome da pessoa estará então na primeira coluna da linha, e o atributo em questão ("Idade", "Sexo", ...) será o cruzamento da linha com a coluna:

```
        nome = sheet.cell_value(row_index, 0)
        valor = sheet.cell_value(row_index, col_index)
```

Falta então formatar esses valores e imprimir. No seu código há um `{}` sobrando:

```
        print "{} - {}".format(nome, valor) # Imprime o nome da pessoa e seu atributo
```

Código completo:

```
for col_index in range(1, sheet.ncols):
    print sheet.cell_value(0, col_index) # Imprime o nome da coluna
    for row_index in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        nome = sheet.cell_value(row_index, 0)
        valor = sheet.cell_value(row_index, col_index)
        print "{} - {}".format(nome, valor) # Imprime o nome da pessoa e seu atributo
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pela explicação, espero poder essa lógica o mais rápido possível. Deu certo. Obrigada